# How do I override a Mojolicious::Controller->new method

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, model-view-controller, mojolicious

Let's assume I have a Mojo controller with a *virtual-esque* method `init` in it.

```
package App::Controller 
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub init {
  my $self = shift;
  # Do things with $self->param('myparam');
}
...
```

And I would like to extend it and make changes to the `init` method.

In this example, I make a subclass `App::Controller::Person` and I want to pull a value out of params and do something different with it.

```
package App::Controller::Person;
use parent 'App::Controller';

sub init {
  my $self = shift;
  # Do different things with $self->param('myparam');
}
...
```

I *want* to be able to inject or call the init method when the Controller is instantiated, but can't seem to figure out how to go about doing that.

Initially, I wanted to just override the `new` method in `App::Controller` by doing something like this:

```
package App::Controller 
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub new {
  my ($class, @args) = @_;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@args);
  $self->init();
  return $self;
}
```

I but didn't have any luck with that.  I'm guessing that I am not passing things correctly to SUPER, but can't seem to figure out what I would need to do in order to get this to work.

How do I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: What does "I didn't have any luck" mean? Your code is working fine. Can you post a minimal example of your usage and what behaviour you expect?

Comment: You call ->param() in your commented code line. Initialization of your Controller is not within a request cycle, so this might be why you think your code does not work?